# Customize the New Item form in Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have a list in SharePoint Hosted Add-in and I want to customize this new item form to have my own customized form.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options -

1. Either go for complete custom, which involves building up the form, actions (preferably using rest) for the new form. This is easier but more developement intensive.
2. you can add a js and css reference to your form and and implement enhancements accordingly. navigate to the new item page, edit it and add the references in a content editor webpart.